# Network drives vanish from "My Computer", even if they're deleted and re-added

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I have a weird situation where I have several mapped network drives which works properly. I can access them by their paths (for example, `N:\`), and they properly show up in the sidebar in windows explorer after I have accessed them.
However, they do not show in the "My Computer" view.

[image]

The output of `net use` looks normal, and everything else works.

What is going on? And how can I make the my computer view show my network drive again?

This happens with multiple different network drives, and I don't have a drive letter conflict.

---

Note that I deleted the network drives, and added them again, and they show up until I close and reopen the My Computer window. At that point, they vanish again.

Comment: Have a look at this, altho [kb231289](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231289). Or  delete them and `add` them again.

Comment: @week - I did delete them and add them again, and they immediately disappeared again.